# Pandas read_excel doesn't read certain xlsx files, returns empty dataframe

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, binance

Hi I wanted to do some work with my binance.com trade exports but it seems as if pandas can't read the orignal nor copies of the original report from binance.

I checked with Nic Scorazzos answer ([Python Pandas read_excel returns empty Dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46180933/python-pandas-read-excel-returns-empty-dataframe)) to see if the file is indeed an excel workbook and not a strict open xml spreadsheet but it seems to me that my file is a workbook.

I checked with the file explorer and the default on 'save as' and it both shows 'Microsoft Excel Workbook (.xlsx)'

Resaving the file as a workbook helps but I want to import them to my python code directly without manually working on them.

I'm on OSX with pandas 1.2 and necessary plugins. Pandas reads other .xlxs files normally, it's just with the binance exports

For those who want to know my code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_excel('binanceExport.xlsx')
df
```

returns

```
Date(UTC)
---------
```

which is the first cell in the spreadsheet

whereas

```
print(df)
```

returns

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Date(UTC)]
Index: []
```

[Screenshot of the spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWyDh.png)

EDIT 1:
I tried saving it as an Open Strict XML Spreadsheet (the other .xlsx) and python returns an `IndexError: list index out of range`

strange, I really believed the original to be an OpenStrictXMLSpreadsheet somehow but as it seems it's not...

Comment: Try changing "engine" parameter of `read_excel`. In particular, try using `openpyxl` engine, because often it's better at wowrking with newer Excel formats.

Comment: hi @pavel, it seems to be a bug on openpyxl's side https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/39250

Answer (score 0):

Try to put more arguments

```
df= read_excel('name.xlsx', sheet_name='')
```

Are the code and the file in the same folder? Try type all path

I thin that the problem is the type of the data. Try to specify to

Comment: I resaved the file as an excel workbook and it solves the problem. But after some digging it seems as it's a Bug on openpyxl's side (see: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/39250)